# Why is this ActiveRecord::Relation (an array of composers) object is being rendered into this view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have an index action in the composers_controller.rb like so:

```
class ComposersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @composers = Composer.all
  end

  def show
    @composer = Composer.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

The instance variable is rendered into this view when visiting http://localhost:3000/composers

```
<h1>Composers</h1>
  <%= @composers.each do |composer| %>
  <div>
    <p><%= composer.name %></p>
    <p>Born: <%= composer.date_of_birth.strftime("%b %-d,  %Y") %></p>
    <p>Died: <%= composer.date_of_death.strftime("%b %-d,  %Y") %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However when I start the server and visit "localhost:3000/composers" in the browser the following view is rendered:
[image]

So why is that array on the bottom being rendered? I have an inkling that this issue is related to the active_admin gem that I am using. Also if it might help here is my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Classical Guide</title>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <div class="container main">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the equals "=" in this line:

```
<%= @composers.each do |composer| %>
```

It should be:

```
<% @composers.each do |composer| %>
```

By including the "=" you are telling erb to render @composers as well. So effectively your iterator now does two things. Firstly, it iterates over the composers as you desire, but secondly, it renders the array of @composers.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for making a silly mistake and asking this question, I promise to be more thorough next time. I'll check this answer in a few minutes, I wish I can check both answers thanks again.

Comment: It's normal. We all forget little things all the time.